# Delete multiple columns whose names share the same suffix

Tags: r

I wanted to delete all the columns with "No", such as DIGSANo, SETFANo, ... How do I do it? Thank you!
The data is here
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jb6gjznyw2q16mx/AADcNKiicqkoHxpFYIsaTgk9a?dl=0)

Comment: Next time, in order to help us to help you, please: specify well what you are trying to achieve, provide some reproducible [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and if possible a desired output. It is harder to help you trying to guess what your purposes are.

Comment: You wouldn't get so many downvotes if you posted some sample data and an attempt to do it yourself. Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be with `dplyr` and the functions that work inside `select`:

```
iris %>% select(-ends_with("Width"))
```

In you case you should do something like:

```
yourData %>% select(-ends_with("No"))
```